# On message delivery guarantee between up-stream/down-stream module instances in Spring-XD in case of container failure

Tags: spring-xd

For example, the stream is defined as Source | Sink. If the container where Sink is deployed fails, I assume Spring-XD runtime will detect the failure (via Zookeeper) and redeploy the Sink instance. Does the message middleware will buffer the messages sent from the Source during the time when the sink is down, and guarantee to deliver to the Sink after it is redeployed? Is there any chance that the data will be lost in the data path? Say, the Sink fails after receiving a message but before handling over to the external sink channel. After the redeployment, that message will not be delivered again to Sink, so it will never appear in the external destination.